# Comparing large powers in Ruby using Mod 10

Tags: ruby, algorithm, numbers, modulus, largenumber

I am trying to write a function that compares whether one number x1 to the power of another number x2 is greater than another number y1 to another number y2 power.

For example, suppose we have a pair of numbers for x.

```
x = [2,10]
```

and another pair y

```
y = [3,9]
```

In this case `y1 ** y2` is greater than `x1 ** x2`.

However, sometimes there are really large, scary numbers. Like so

```
x = [935243113, 987702643]
y = [50894069, 704259526]
```

To calculate this, I tried using the mod 10 algorithm

```
(x[0] ** x[1]) % 10 > (y[0] ** y[1]) % 10
```

However, apparently this algorithm doesn't work. Is there a more efficient algorithm for this.

Comment: Does that even work in theory? I don't see why comparing the mod10 result should say anything about the order of the full results. Counter example: `10**10` vs `9**9`

Comment: I found that algorithm through Stack Overflow. It probably should

Comment: Ok, let me disprove it even harder: consider a list of more than 10 different powers, at best there are 10 different results modulo 10 so at least two of them get the same result and will compare "equal" (neither bigger than the other) even though we just assumed they were different.

Comment: `(x[0] ** x[1]) % 10` still calculates `x[0] ** x[1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a mod 10 for arbitrary sums and comparing them is not much different from taking random numbers. You cannot avoid the scale of your numbers here. The modulo *might* help for determining if the two numbers are equal (you can assume they are not equal if the sum modulo any number is not equal). Also note that Ruby will still calculate the large numbers in your case - but there are tricks you can use to avoid that if you do the exponentiation in more detail in modulo arithmetic.

For an approximate method, that should work *almost* all the time, then you can use the fact that Math.log( x ** y ) == y * Math.log( x ).

Like this:

```
(Math.log(x[0]) * x[1]) > (Math.log(y[0]) * y[1])
```

When I say *almost*, I mean that you expose yourself to floating point inaccuracies here. It may be possible for two extremely large, but very similar exponentiations to come out in wrong order due to rounding in `Math.log`. I am not sure if it is a practical issue for numbers of the size you are showing.

Update:

```
2 ** 9 == 8 ** 3
# => true
```

but

```
(Math.log(2) * 9) > (Math.log(8) * 3)
# => true
```

so rounding errors on exactly equal values are a more serious problem, and can occur for quite low input numbers. If it is possible for two inputs to be equal and important to know whether the values are strictly different, you need to fall back to a different mechanism when the results from the log/log comparison are very close, e.g. the ratio of the two log sums is within 1e-6 of 1.0.